# How do I change the color of a brick?

Tags: colour, customization

I have a uniquely-shaped brick that I would like to make a darker shade of gray (it's currently blue).

- What media is the best in terms of durability for continued use (i.e. re-use, re-configuration)?
- I assume a spray media would work well, is there a particular type of paint to use that would have a harder surface and be less prone to scratching, sticking?

Comment: In our impressionable youth, my brother and I painted a few mini-figures and helmets. We had no real long term success with acrylics. Enamel paints worked better - I'll have a rummage over the weekend and see how badly scratched they are.

Comment: Note that, with spray paint, the paint might pool in the corners and crevices of the brick, so I would not use that if I were you.

Comment: I wouldn't paint any of the mating surfaces. Mask those off to protect them from overspray (if spraying).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think that spray paint would be very durable.  Even if you used a primer specifically designed for plastic the paint would scratch off fairly easily.  Also, spray paint would add a noticeable amount of thickness to the brick and could interfere when trying to mate the brick up with others.

Answer (score 20):

The problem is that bricks are coloured throughout,  not just surface coloured, which means any paint you add will wear off.

My guidance is to source a brick in the colour you need and replace it.

Answer (score 17):

If it's for a display model (static on a shelf) you could use scale model paint and varnish.  Matching the original color will be hard, so don't expect perfection.

On the other hand, if your looking to 'play' with that piece afterward, I don't think any paint method can resist that abuse.  like mentioned by Rory Alsop you're better off finding the real thing.

Answer (score 16):

According to [Auto Body Repair](http://books.google.com/books?id=zh94U0W_hwsC&lpg=PA849&dq=what%20is%20the%20best%20paint%20for%20acrylonitrile%20butadiene%20styrene&pg=PA849#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Duffy and Sharff, the best solution for any interior or exterior (non-flexible) ABS (acrylonitrile butadiene styrene, the plastic LEGO elements are made of) component is to apply a standard lacquer based system, no primer.

Answer (score 10):

It's Lego blasphemy to change the color of the bricks (or to modify them using, say, a dremmel) but that said I would use the spray paint that is made for plastic. Of course, whenever I go to Lowes the color selection is limited so you may not find the color you need.

Comment: nor would it be likely to match any of your other bricks.

Comment: Actually, designers do spray existing pieces when they need to use a not-yet-produced color in their test models. It's hard to speak of blasphemy when even supernatural beings do it.

Answer (score 8):

Use clothing dye to change the color. It works for wear and tear. It doesn't wear off. It dyes the part rather than coating it.

Comment: I don't know who bothered to down-vote this answer, but even Iain Heath likes this method. http://www.brothers-brick.com/2013/06/30/50-shades-of-bley-iain-heaths-mad-lego-science/

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of a new method: Order custom sticker sheets and apply the stickers. Might be tough to get the color right, though.

Answer (score -1):

Hm, maybe try using British Paints Spray Paint. I think they are the best brand. Just make SURE that it is the exact same colour with the other ones you are using. Spray at about 35-40cm distance from the block. I tried it and it works well.

Comment: Hi Anonymous! While this is a nice answer, it would definitely benefit from some additional details. For example, why do you think that is the best brand? What properties distinguish it from the others? What was the colour combination you used (LEGO brick colour and paint colour)? Is there anything one should be careful with when applying the paint?

Answer (score -2):

If it's on display, then paint it, use water colour paints, or use permanent marker. They all work well.