# How Can I paint my LEGO Bricks?

Tags: customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the color of a brick?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-brick)

Is there a way that I can paint a white LEGO brick?  I would prefer paints that will not come off easily.

Comment: Rather similar to our first ever question: [How do I change the color of a brick](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1/56)

Answer (score 2):

Years ago for one of my projects. I used some acrylic paint to match something with the rest of the building. It can be done. But removing the paint is going to be a pain in the tail feathers. The parts never did look right after that. So I advise against it.